# I can't designate barracks

Tags: dwarf-fortress

According to [the barracks wiki page](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Barracks), beds, cabinets, chests, bags, weapon racks, or armor stands can be used to make a barracks. I have built an armor and weapon rack in a room, but it is not giving me the `r` button option to make a barracks. What am I missing?

[Link to save](http://dffd.wimbli.com/file.php?id=10112)

[image: Screenshot showing current layout. Including selected armor stand]

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: That was me and because one of my pet peeves is people asking questions about modded games and not bothering to mention it

Comment: @Studoku You might want to rethink your philosophy there... especially considering DFHack is basically standard.

Comment: I don't use it. Also, considering it turned out to be **entirely the cause of the problem you had**, I feel justified here.

Comment: This is a useful question and answer, I had the same problem. Anyone using the lazy newb pack could run into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I'm using DFHack, so for all of my previous room assignments (ie bed to bedroom, chair to office)I just clicked on the tile to make it work. This doesn't work for barracks, so I instead need to use the <kbd>q</kbd> key explicitly.